# Flask __init__.py doesn't show changes

Tags: python, flask

When I try to update the **__init__**.py file in Flask, it doesn't show the changes in the server, but when I edit `home.html` it works fine.

app/**__init__**.py

```
 import os
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')

    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    app.debug = bool(os.environ.get('PRODUCTION'))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Any tips?

Comment: Change to `app.run(debug=True)`.

Comment: You have to reload or if you are on development turn on `debug=True`

Comment: No luck... changed `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)` but still won't update.

Comment: Do you use an application server like uWSGI or just running development server?

Comment: Yes, I run a uWSGI (nginx) server.

Comment: Ok, and now the question is do you restart your server after the change of __init__ file?

Comment: Yes, I used the following command `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` to restart my nginx server

Comment: Problem solved! After rebooting the server with `sudo reboot`, it seems working great! Thank you @PiotrDawidiuk!

Comment: I would restart uWSGI, not nginx.

Comment: @KaiWen I recommend not to restart your server with sudo reboot, I meant to restart uWSGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem in comments but I will add solution here if someone else has a similar problem.

**For development environment** add `debug=True` argument to your app

`app.run(debug=True)`

If your development environment works on an application server, then you should look for autoreload option. In uWSGI there is [py-auto-reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#py-auto-reload) for example.

**For released, stable environment** you should restart your application server.

For example in **uWSGI**

> There are several ways to make uWSGI gracefully restart.
>
> ```
> # using kill to send the signal
> kill -HUP `cat /tmp/project-master.pid`
> # or the convenience option --reload
> uwsgi --reload /tmp/project-master.pid
> # or if uwsgi was started with touch-reload=/tmp/somefile
> touch /tmp/somefile
> ```

More: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server

**Warning**: if you combine application and web server, uWSGI and Nginx for example, then restarting Nginx won't reload your application code. Focus on the application server.